# Unable to load Visual Studio debugger component (VS 2019)

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I keep getting the error mentioned in the title and shown in the attached image. This is on a fresh installation of VS 2019 Community edition and new .NET framework console application project. I have thoroughly googled for the error and tried all solutions I could find online and even contacted Microsoft Support chat, but no solutions have worked so far. I made a forum post on the VS developer community as well but it has been a week and I haven't heard from anyone. I have never experienced this issue before, this happens in any project/solution I open.

This exact is issue reported on the VS developer forum but the answer there was to download the latest version of Visual studio which I do have (16.7.4), yet the error still persists. There are similar issues here on stack

Here are the things that I’ve tried:

- Repaired installation
- Ran `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe -full`
- Uninstalled and reinstalled
- Restarted PC
- Checked if `vsdebugeng.impl.dll` exists in `[VSInstallDir]\Common7\Packages\Debugger\`, `[VSInstallDir]\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x86\` and `[VSInstallDir]\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\`
- Ran VS in safe mode and with administrative privileges

I haven’t tried installing an earlier version of visual studio though, would that be my only solution? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

[image: Error message]

Comment: Having the same problem here, Were you able to fix this ?

Comment: I did, yes. I had to reformat windows on my PC from the Enterprise edition to Home. Still no reply from Microsoft support either, so don't know what the root cause of it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by formatting my PC from Windows 10 Enterprise edition to Home.